# What configurations can miners set to select transactions to execute from their pool?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethminer, miner

I know every miner has a pool of pending transactions (those are waiting to be executed). The miner can decide which transactions to execute and include in his block.However, miner is not setting and selecting transactions by himself, rather miner usually uses a configurable software to select specific transactions.

My question is what the miner can configure in selecting transactions apart from transaction fees and size??

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, "[A] miner usually uses a configurable software to select specific transactions", so to answer your question of "what can the miner configure", depends entirely on what software they're using to mine with.

If using the default Mist/Geth node, there's no configuration of which particular transactions available to the miner; the software picks the best ones for them automatically. If using a different mining tool, it would be up to the developers of that tool what configuration options to put in, and you'd have to peruse the documentation or ask the developers directly what options there are.

Comment: Thank you so much. I mean what attributes can a miner configure? assume i am a developer to build a mining tool and would like to have a control of all possible attributes (tx size, fees, or ignore all tx), what can be allowed to me? e.g., i would like to generate empty blocks without executing any transaction (just get the block reward), would this possible if i used my own tool? Thanks again

Comment: A developer creating a mining program could have access to any attributes about new transactions. Using the JSON RPC `eth_newPendingTransactionFilter` filter, any service can get the whole transaction payload whenever that node receives a new transaction into the mempool (waiting to be mined). You could then use whatever criteria you want, parsed from the whole transaction's data to decide if you want to mine it. And yes, it's possible to mine an empty block, that's totally allowable with the current protocol.